# Estimating risk ratio instead of odds ratio in mixed effect logistic regression in `R`

Tags: r, lme4

`glmer` is used to estimate effects on the logit scale of `y` when the data are clustered. In the following model

```
fit1 = glmer(y ~ treat + x + ( 1 | cluster), family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

the `exp` of the coefficient of `treat` is the odds ratio of a binary `0-1` treatment variable, `x` is a covariate, and `cluster` is a clustering indicator across which we model a random effect (intercept). A standard approach in `glm`'s to estimate risk ratios is to use a `log` link instead, i.e. `family=binomial(link = "log")`. However using this in `glmer` I get error

```
Error in (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L, maxit = 100L,  : 
  (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate
```

after calling

```
fit1 = glmer(y ~ treat + x + ( 1 | cluster), family = binomial(link = "log"))
```

A web search revealed other people had similar issues with the `Gamma` family.

This seems to be a general problem as the reproducible example below demonstrates. My question thus is: how can I estimate risk ratios using a mixed effect model like `glmer`?

**Reproducible Example**
The following code simulates data that replicates the problem.

```
n = 1000                            # sample size
m = 50                              # number of clusters
J = sample(1:m, n, replace = T)     # simulate cluster membership
x = rnorm(n)                        # simulate covariate
treat = rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)           # simulate random treatment
u  = rnorm(m)                       # simulate random intercepts
lt = x + treat + u[J]               # compute linear term of logistic mixed effect model
p  = 1/(1+exp(-lt))                 # use logit link to transform to probabilities
y  = rbinom(n,1,p)                  # draw binomial outcomes
d  = data.frame(y, x, treat)

# First fit logistic model with glmer
fit1  = glmer( y ~ treat + x + (1 | as.factor(J)), 
               family = binomial(link = "logit"), data  = d) 
summary(fit1)

# Now try to log link    
fit2  = glmer( y ~ treat + x + (1 | as.factor(J)), 
               family = binomial(link = "log"), data  = d)
```

Comment: I think you will get more help on CrossValidated as this is a more statistical problem than coding problem. P.S. If you can make a reproducible example that will help people determine the cause of the error.

Comment: @emilliman5 yes I was doubtful myself where is the better outlet... a replicable example will take a moment to produce. An answer / comment that tells me that this is general not possible in `glmer` would also help.

Comment: A reproducible example would be great.  The general issue (which is *still* not solved) is (I think) the same as the one documented in gory detail here: https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/573. When you use a link function that does not constrain the predictions to be within the feasible space of the distribution (e.g. log-link allows probabilities > 1), glmer is fragile. Things you could try: (1) *maybe* glmmTMB would work? (2) adjust starting values? (3) skip nAGQ0 init step (see link)?

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks! I will try to come up with something. Do you think binomial family with log link is generally the way to go to solve this estimation problem?

Comment: It's certainly one reasonable way. Presumably you can also generate risk ratios *post hoc* by doing computations using appropriate predictions based on the fitted logit model (I'm sure this is possible but it would take some time to work out how to do it https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183908/calculating-risk-ratio-using-odds-ratio-from-logistic-regression-coefficient  https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-12-14

Comment: @BenBolker I have added a reproducible example, perhaps this helps! I would prefer to get it to run this way.

Comment: @BenBolker Sorry I do not mean to be obtrusive; just wondering if you have any other thoughts after you see the example (no problem if not; just want to make sure you saw the thread/update) :)

Comment: `?binomial` clearly states that for the binomial family the links can either be  `logit`, `probit` or `cauchit`

Answer (score 2):

[This error](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#which-r-packages-functions-fit-glmms) is returned due to your model producing values > 1:

> - `PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate`
>   ...
>
>   - When using `lme4` to fit GLMMs with link functions that do not automatically constrain the response to the allowable range of the distributional family (e.g. binomial models with a log link, where the estimated probability can be >1, or inverse-Gamma models, where the estimated mean can be negative), it is not unusual to get this error. This occurs because `lme4` doesn’t do anything to constrain the predicted values, so `NaN` values pop up, which aren’t handled gracefully. If possible, switch to a link function to one that constrains the response (e.g. logit link for binomial or log link for Gamma).

Unfortunately, the suggested workaround is to use a different link function.

The following paper surveys a number of alternative model choices for calculation for [adjusted] relative risk:

- [Model choices to obtain adjusted risk difference estimates from a binomial regression model with convergence problems: An assessment of methods of adjusted risk difference estimation](https://www.hoajonline.com/journals/pdf/2053-7662-4-5.pdf) (2016)

Comment: This is a great answer. It is unfortunate that a different link function is the suggested workaround.